# Wowza installer continue asking for JAVA_HOME but it is specified

Tags: java, installation, wowza, java-home

I have installation issue with Wowza Streaming Engine.
I'm continue to get the following error:

```
---------------------------
Java JDK or Java Server JRE Required
---------------------------
A JAVA_HOME environment variable pointing at a Java JDK or server JRE v1.6 or higher is required to install the Wowza Streaming Engine. The installer will now exit.

For more information go to http://www.wowza.com/jvm.

Would you like for the installer to take you there before exiting?
---------------------------
Yes   No   
---------------------------
```

Java JDK JRE 1.7 installed and JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables are updated.
What else should I change to pass through the installer check.

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vsi4wi9v6iytku8/java_wowza.png]

Comment: is it JRE or JDK1.7 installed? if its JRE may be it requires JDK, try installing JDK.

Comment: I have jre only installed

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that java portal chosen a wrong processor architecture and I downloaded and installed x86 version. I was forced to manually switch to x64 JRE, download it and re-isntall java.

After that everything start working as expected.